# Extract data from XML file with similar Blocks

Tags: xml, linux, soap, xmlstarlet, xmllint

**Source**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <lima2t:runlargeResponse xmlns:lima2t="uri://Metadata.com/home/1.0">
        <data>
          <capacity>
              <name>Everyday.Italian.Dish</name>
              <currency>($)</currency>
              <CashAmount>not.used.for.this.transaction</CashAmount>
              <CheckAmount>not.used.for.this.transaction</CheckAmount>
              <CreditAmount>not.used.for.this.transaction</CreditAmount>
          </capacity>
          <capacity>
              <name>Everyday.French.Dish</name>
              <currency>($)</currency>
              <CashAmount>not.used.for.this.transaction</CashAmount>
              <CheckAmount>not.used.for.this.transaction</CheckAmount>
              <CreditAmount>134,70</CreditAmount>
          </capacity>
      </data>
    </lima2t:runlargeResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Goal** Extract:

`134,70` from `<CreditAmount>134,70</CreditAmount>`

I tried this Command, but the command outputs everything on the screen

```
xmllint --path '//soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/soap:Body/lima2t:runlargeResponse xmlns:lima2t="uri://Metadata.com/home/1.0"/data/capacity/@name="Everyday.French.Dish"/CreditAmount/text()' op.xml
```

I feel like something is missing but I can't find what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
xmllint --xpath '
    //data/capacity[name="Everyday.French.Dish"]/CreditAmount/text()
' op.xml
```

Or using shell switch (need extra post processing to remove garbage):

```
xmllint --shell op.xml<<EOF
cat //data/capacity[name="Everyday.French.Dish"]/CreditAmount/text()
EOF
```

Or using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '
    //data/capacity[name="Everyday.French.Dish"]/CreditAmount/text()
' op.xml
```

### Output:

```
134,70
```

Comment: error:  "Unknown option --xpath"
--xpath is not available, but --path is available. when I use --path it outputs the entire op.xml file on the screen

Comment: Which OS/version ? Which `xmllint` version ? `xmllint --version` (20904 for me)

Comment: `xmllint: using libxml version 20706`

`CentOS release 6.8`
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib

Comment: Asked OS/version too. Could you install `xmlstarlet` ?

Comment: `xmllint: using libxml version 20706`

`CentOS release 6.8`
yes!! indeed I already have `xmlstarlet`

Comment: fantastic `xmlstarlet` worked for me, thanks for your help

Comment: You _could_ simplify to just one predicate: `//data/capacity[name='Everyday.French.Dish']/CreditAmount/text()`

Comment: @DanielHaley thanks. Why there's no need to compare with `text()` ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot - Because the string value of `name` is used in the comparison. From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#booleans): _If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a string, then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the node-set such that the result of performing the **comparison on the string-value of the node** and the other string is true._ If `name` was `<name><x>Everyday</x>.<y>French</y>.<z>Dish</z></name>` then `name='Everyday.French.Dish'` would still be true.